# Appropriate use of Java generics on collection

Tags: java, generics, collections, wildcard

I've never had the chance to play much with generics before (as in writing classes that are generics), but now the need arises, and I've come across some confusion.

There's this interface, that is meant to be a wrapper of *something*. The implementations are not collections, so, every instance has access only to one *something*.

```
public interface Resource<T> {
    // Expected operations:
    void write(ResourceState state);
    ResourceState read();
}
```

As implementations, I expect to have an `ExclusiveResource<T>`, and a `ShareableResource<T>`, that differ mainly/only in the locking scheme used (regular lock, and read-write lock, respectively).
As to how the `read` and `write` are performed, I'm planning on using the **Strategy** pattern.
For instance, I might have

```
// This would implement a Strategy<File>.
FileStrategy fs = new FileStrategy();
Resource<File> r = new ExclusiveResource<File>(fs);
```

Now, I've also got some sort  of *collection* of these resources, say, a resource pool.
I'd like to map a key to each resource, in the resource pool, and I'd like to add, retrieve and remove resources, but I'm not sure how to declare the map and the methods. I've tried the following:

```
public class ResourcePool {
    // instance variables
    private final Map<String, Resource<?>> map;

    /** Empty constructor of objects of class ResourcePool. */
    public ResourcePool() {
        map = new HashMap<String, Resource<?>>();
    }

    /** */
    public Resource<?> get(String s) {
        return map.get(s);
    }

    /** */
    public void add(String s, Resource<?> r) {
        map.put(s, r);
    }

    // ...
}
```

This does not seem to be the most appropriate way to do it, and, quoting Josh Bloch, on [*Effective Java Reloaded*](https://sites.google.com/site/io/effective-java-reloaded):

> User should not have to think about wildcards to use your API.

I've tested this code with the following method:

```
public static void test() {
    ResourcePool rp = new ResourcePool();

    Resource<String> r1 = new ShareableResource<>("test");
    Resource<Integer> r2 = new ShareableResource<>(1);
    Resource<List<String>> r3 = new ShareableResource<>(
            Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1", "2"})
    );

    // These are all ok.
    rp.add("1", r1);
    rp.add("2", r2);
    rp.add("3", r3);

    // This results in a compiler error (incompatible types).
    Resource<String> g1 = rp.get("1");

    // This results in a compiler warning (unsafe operation).
    Resource<String> g2 = (Resource<String>) rp.get("1");
}
```

I don't like it, when the code compiles with warnings. Makes me feel guilty, and seems to be a hint at bad coding.

So, my question is how should I handle this situation.
**Is this the right way to do what I'm trying to do?**
Can this be done in such a way that there are no unsafe operations?

Comment: I think it would be necessary to see the implementations of Resource to solve this one.  I think your best bet is removing the generic type from resource and just working with the plain interface.

Comment: @KevinBowersox I didn't include any more details on resources, fearing that the question might get a bit too long, but I'll update it with what I intend to do with the resources, and what implementations are expected.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any way to avoid the unsafe casts.  Think about generic types your familiar with such as `List<E>`.  Now imagine having a `List<List<?>>` how could you work with this parameterized type in a type safe manner?  I'm not sure you can.  You would never know the type being returned by the list unless you had intimate knowledge of what was contained at each item in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to avoid unchecked casts using your design. That said, you can avoid having to do a cast every time you retrieve a `Resource`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> Resource<T> get(String s, Class<T> c) {
    return (Resource<T>) map.get(s);
}
```

When you want to retrieve a `Resource`, you pass in the desired class, like so:

```
Resource<String> g1 = rp.get("1", String.class);
```

You should be careful with this design, though, since there will be no runtime guarantee that the returned `Resource` is actually a `Resource<String>`.

Comment: Yes, I thought there would be no way to avoid all that. However, now you had me thinking if I really need the generic at all. This is supposed to be extensible, so I thought that, by using a generic, I could ask in the constructor for a specific strategy to each kind of resource (see updated question).

Comment: @afsantos I'll add another answer, since it's a different way to address the problem

Comment: Even though I'm not sure I'll use this suggestion, I'll mark your answer as accepted. My thoughts shifted to the design and usage of the Resources, and I'll post another question on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could create different collections for each type of resource you want, and make `ResourcePool` generic also:

```
ResourcePool<String> stringpool = new ResourcePool<String>();
ResourcePool<Integer> intpool = new ResourcePool<Integer>();
```

This would give you the benefits of compile-time checking on your types. And it seems that you know what type you want whenever you get something out of the `ResourcePool`, so you can select the appropriate collection.